# why this form is a PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

why is an n by n matrix W minus the $\lambda_{min}$ of W I a PSD matrix? I mean, I cannot think of why this is true off the top of my head, is there a trick here?
The whole expression is: $W - \lambda_{min}(W)I \succeq 0$. The book doesn't define what $\lambda $ is, but I think it means the eigenvalue of W.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1 > \ldots  >\lambda_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $W$ in decreasing order. The eigenvalue decomposition is 
$$W = PDP^{-1}$$
where $P,D$ contain the eigenvectors/values of $W$. Note that 
$$ W - \lambda_nI  = PDP^{-1} - \lambda_nI = PDP^{-1} - \lambda_n PP^{-1} = P(D - \lambda_nI)P^{-1}$$
So, $W - \lambda_n I$ is a matrix where its eigenvalues are $$\lambda_1 - \lambda_n > \lambda_2 - \lambda_n > \ldots > 0$$
In other words, the smallest eigenvalue of $W - \lambda_n I$ is $0$.